# Is 'this' truly a reference to "$scope" in AngularJS's context?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend

I'm quite new to the superheroic framework AngularJS, so please excuse my noobness! So, while I was trying to develop a simple SPA that allowed admins to change permissions of other users in my website through a table filled with selection checkboxes, I came by an issue. I defined `$scope.checked` so I could know how many users the administrator chose and also `$scope.mainCheckBox` which would hold the correct CSS class for the major checkbox (like the one from Gmail, which you use to select all/none) in each of the three situations: all users selected, no users selected and partial selection. This simple logic goes as follows:

```
$scope.updateMainCheckBox = function(){

    if(this.checked==this.users.length) this.mainCheckBox = "qm-icon-checked";
    else if(!this.checked) this.mainCheckBox = "";
    else this.mainCheckBox = "qm-icon-minus";

};
```

Running this at the end of the ng-click event callback of the other checkboxes, this code was capable of choosing the class correctly but it wouldn't assign the class to the `mainCheckBox`. When I changed every `this.mainCheckBox`to `$scope.mainCheckBox` it all went well and the page would behave as expected.

So, I know in vanilla Js `this` is a reference to the `window` object but since AngularJS has its own event handling loop, I believe that's not the case now. I expected it to be a ref to `$scope`, since `checked` and `users` were found, but apparently it's not. So, what's happening here? And also, is there a more "angular" way to implement this?

Comment: Is this function called from inside an `ng-repeat` element?

Comment: Yes, it's called in the end of the ng-click callback of a `<div>` inside the `<tr ng-repeat="user in users">` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mostly right--in the case of your function, `this` did reference a scope. But, it did not reference `$scope`; instead, it referenced one of `$scope`'s children.

Try this: add some `console.log` statements to log out the ID of the `$scope` variable, and then the ID of the `this` scope in your callback:

```
$scope.updateMainCheckBox = function(){
  console.log('$scope:', $scope.$id);
  console.log('this:', this.$id);
  // ...
};
```

You'll find the IDs are different. This is because the `ngRepeat` directive creates a *child scope*, which is a scope that inherits prototypally from its parent. This means that when you assign directly to a value on that scope, it's not reaching the *parent* scope, which is `$scope`.

I **highly** recommend a read through the excellent (and lengthy) ["The Nuances of Scope Prototypal Inheritance"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14049482/62082) by [Mark Rajcok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215945/mark-rajcok); it esplains why you see this seemingly strange behavior on child scopes. (You can also find [a copy on the AngularJS wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/The-Nuances-of-Scope-Prototypal-Inheritance).)

Comment: Another good SO question/answer I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers/14168699#14168699

Comment: Cool, I think I got it! Prototypal inheritance is weird, I'm still not used to it completely and thanks, I didn't know nested directives could create child scopes! Now it makes sense!